# Как убрать кавычки из массива?

Tags: javascript

1 Есть код

```
function completeFn({data}) { 
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        var ready = data.map(function(item) {return [item.Time_ms, item.VarValue]});}
        console.log(ready);
```

2 Выводится в консоле так:

```
0: Array [ "43614696006,875", "0" ]
```

3 Как убрать кавычки? Надо так:

```
 0: Array [ 43614696006, 0 ]
```

​

Comment: вы хотите в int ковертнуть вот это - 43614696006,875 ?

Comment: @splash58, да мне это значение нужно в int и без кавычек, 2-е значение тоже без кавычек.

Comment: `parseInt` должно сработать

Comment: @splash58, спасибо, делаю так `var d = parseInt(ready);` В Int переводит только первое значение, как сделать, чтоб и 2-е тоже перевёл?

Comment: return [parseInt(item.Time_ms), parseInt(item.VarValue)]

Comment: @splash58,спасибо. Как можно здесь Вам галочку поставить?

Comment: тут - никак. достаточно одной :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно изменить тип данных

в инт

```
var text = '42px';
var integer = parseInt(text, 10);
// returns 42
```

в намбер

```
// Convert strings
Number('123'); // returns 123
Number('12.3'); // returns 12.3
Number('3.14someRandomStuff'); // returns NaN
Number('42px'); // returns NaN
```

Подробнее можно почитать тут [converting-strings-to-numbers](https://gomakethings.com/converting-strings-to-numbers-with-vanilla-javascript/)

Comment: `Number('123')` == `+'123'`